# How to get all user details in rest api wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rest

I am trying to get all the user details from wordpress 4.7 through the rest api - wp-json/wp/v2/users.

Currently I am seeing a lot of fields for the user object (close to 100 fields, amr user plugin installed) in the wordpress site, but the api is returning very few fields.

How can I get all the fields of user object in the rest api, should I install any other plugin for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You are only receiving the user fields which are stored in the **wp_users** table, but not the fields which are stored in the **wp_usermeta** table.

In order to get all information about a user, you have to get the **user meta fields** of this user from the REST API.

How to get user meta fields from the REST API:

Look into register_rest_field() to register meta with the rest api.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'adding_user_meta_rest' );

function adding_user_meta_rest() {
   register_rest_field( 'user',
                        'collapsed_widgets',
                         array(
                           'get_callback'      => 'user_meta_callback',
                           'update_callback'   => null,
                           'schema'            => null,
                            )
                      );
}
```

And then put your get_user_meta bit in the callback.

function user_meta_callback( $user, $field_name, $request) {
       return get_user_meta( $user[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );
   }

The [WP_REST_Meta_Fields class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_meta_fields/) may provide more useful insight as well.

The later part of this answer I have found in this answer on WordPress Stackexchange: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270154/getting-user-meta-data-from-wp-rest-api

Comment: Thanks Blackbam. But where will I get the code of this REST API. Should I have the wordpress code in my system to do this?. Can I edit through the wordpress admin site?

Comment: You should add your code by creating either a child theme or a Plugin.

Comment: Blackbam, I have put your code as a plugin and installed it successfully but it still doesn't give the response in the users api.

Comment: It would be really great if you can guide me in this, expecting your response.

Comment: Below is my code <?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'adding_user_meta_rest' );
function adding_user_meta_rest() {
   register_rest_field( 'user',
                        'collapsed_widgets',
                         array(
                           'get_callback'      => 'user_meta_callback',
                           'update_callback'   => null,
                           'schema'            => null,
                            )
                      );
}
 function user_meta_callback( $user, $field_name, $request) {
return get_user_meta( $user[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );}